# Angular a 3 way If else condition in the component.html

Tags: angular, angular12

I am using Angular 12 and in my component.html I need to have a 3 level condition.

For example:

I have a list and I need to check if it contains a string or not.

The true and false state both have a different output and finally I need to ELSE for any other condition.

So...First I have one condition:

```html
<div *ngIf="list.includes('sometext') && listitem === null ">Condition 1</div>
```

Now a condition with the reverse of the above:

```html
<div *ngIf="!list.includes('sometext') && listitem === null ">Condition 2</div>
```

And finally the ELSE:

```html
<div>Condition 3 or Any other condition from the others above</div>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Just a recommendation as answered below: Have you thought of using a method or service to show the condition values? Then you don't need to worry about adding extra tag everytime a new condition arrives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement it in such way:

```js
<ng-container *ngIf="listitem; else noListItemTmpl">
    <div>Condition 3 or Any other condition from the others above</div>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #noListItemTmpl>
    <div *ngIf="list.includes('sometext')">Condition 1</div>
    <div *ngIf="!list.includes('sometext')">Condition 2</div>
</ng-template>
```

No nasty `listitem === null` checks.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to solve this problem is to use `ngSwitchCase` insead of `ngIf`  as shown below:

```html
<container-element [ngSwitch]="true">
   <some-element *ngSwitchCase="list.includes('sometext') && listitem === null ">...</some-element>
   <some-element *ngSwitchCase="!list.includes('sometext') && listitem === null ">...</some-element>
   <some-element *ngSwitchDefault>Condition 3 or Any other condition from the others above</some-element>
</container-element>
```

Comment: That's not true: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#description

Comment: why? you have only 1 else, to continue with further adding "else if" cases nested templates would be required, which looks dirty

Comment: You said that `Angular ngIf doesn't support else if or something simillar...`. That's not true. If that's looks dirty or not, that's a personal opinion. Angular supports `else` functionality.

Comment: i fixed the post by signing out "else if" explicitly, sory for misunderstanding

Comment: Again you are wrong, Your solution is very elegant indeed. But putting an `if` inside an `else` block is equals with doing an `else if`.

Comment: @Andrei , what we can achieve with `ngSwitchCase` is also completely possible with `ngIf` using `ng-template`. However, your solution is the correct way to do it. That is whay I have updated the answer.

Comment: I assumed puting one more if inside of a else block is obvious for anyone. with this assumption the answer should be ok

Answer (score 1):

nested if statements would make it easy to read.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="listitem === null; else third">
   <div *ngIf="list.includes('sometext')">Condition 1</div>
   <div *ngIf="!list.includes('sometext')">Condition 2</div>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #third>
   <div>Condition 3 or Any other condition from the others above</div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I get an error...Unexpected closing tag on the code above

Comment: typo (: it is fixed